# Edit container project files from host

Tags: docker, jhipster

I'm using `jhipster` docker image to generate a `jhipster` project on an `ubuntu` 12.04.

My issue is that when I'd like to edit my files on host, these files are not owned by me. I've made some search, but found nothing.

The only idea I have is to chown the project.

Is there a clean way to edit these files from my IDE (or any text editor on my host)?

There is already a topic about it, but rather old and I'd like to use my IDE. Not edit files one by one.

Comment: What image are you using? How are you running your docker command? you should be able to install docker so you don't need sudo to run the command.

Comment: I'm following jhipster instruction (Docker Installation on this page : http://jhipster.github.io/installation.html). But locally files are owned by user 1001 of group 1001.

Comment: you could try ti install the docker vm (in case you are on windows or mac) or the docker program using the official installation instructions and try again: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

Comment: I have done it last week.